# access object with dynamic variable vue.js

Tags: vue.js

This is my object

```
var users ={
  twitter : {
     name : //,
     lastname : //
  },
  facebook : {
     name : //,
     lastname : //
  }
}
}
```

I have a dynamic variable activeuser that updates from Facebook to twitter.
What i'm trying to do is refer to the inner object in users depending on the value of activeuser. I need to give my div something like this class :

```
<div class=' {{users.activeuser}}'></div>
```

I know this is not how it should be done with vue.js. Do you have any suggestions?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using VueJS you should be able to assign your dynamic variable to a Vue Model when you load the new object using a Vue setter `$set('property name', 'value')`

Example [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) retreival:

```
$.getJSON('myURL.html?query=xxx', function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    try{
        MyVue.$set('dynamicObject', data);
    }
    catch(e){}

});
```

A generic [Vue](http://vuejs.org/guide/index.html#A_Quick_Example) may look like this:

```
var MyVue = new Vue({
el:'#exampleDiv',
data: {
           dynamicObject : ''
      }
});
```

Bound to an example HTML element:

```
<div id="exampleDiv">
    <label class="{{dynamicObject.activeuser}}">{{dynamicObject.username}}</label>
</div>
```

In the case that you have an object with an array of objects which also contain properties Vue makes it very simple to create many HTML elements (for each child object) by simply adding a `v-repeat` ([example](http://vuejs.org/guide/list.html)) to the desired HTML and assigning the datasource:

```
<div id="exampleDiv">
    <label v-repeat="dynamicObject" class="{{dynamicObject.activeuser}}"></label>
</div>
```